# EC2 yum 404 error

Tags: amazon-ec2, http-status-code-404, yum

I'm using an instance of Amazon EC2, Redhat.

Since I updated yum last time, it doesn't work any more, always get error messages of 404 not found, for example:

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://rhui2-cds01.us-east-2.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/%24releasever/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
https://rhui2-cds02.us-east-2.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/%24releasever/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to redhat https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

> Typical Cause This issue generally occurs if client system is able to
>   communicate with given server but could not find or access the
>   requested package on the server.
>
> Resolution This issue can occur due to corruption of local client
>   cache, try to clear cache on client system:

Try

```
rm -fr /var/cache/yum/* 
yum clean all
```

then

```
yum update
```